# Not Able To Set Value Of Web Form Text Field With VB.Net Due To Duplicate Element IDs

Tags: html, vb.net, internet-explorer, web-scraping

I am trying to fill in a web form with VB.Net and am encountering a problem with a field on the Web Form because the same name of the "id" property is used twice in a row.

See below for an example of the HTML. The first on is the one that works. It's the "ClientAccountNumber" field.

Below that is the "ClientAccession" field and is the one that is not working.

"ClientAccountNumber" field (One That Works)

```
<td>

    <span class="zenLabel" id="zenlbl_22">Client Account Number</span>

    <div>

        <input class="text" id="ClientAccountNumber" type="text" size="30" value="TM123456P">

    </div>

</td>
```

[image: ClientAccountNumber Field]

"ClientAccession" field (Does Not Work)

```
<td>

    <span class="QLSLabelReq" id="zenlbl_17">Client Accession</span>

    <div id="ClientAccession" value="TM123456P">

        <input class="text" id="ClientAccession" type="text" size="30">

    </div>

</td>
```

[image: ClientAccession field]

As you can see, I can set the "value" of the "ClientAccountNumber" field just fine.

But I am having issues setting the "value" of the "ClientAccession" field because the person who originally did the HTML used the "id" of "ClientAccession" two times in a row.

Now it sets the "value" of the first "ClientAccession" and I'm not able to get at the second "ClientAccession" so the form field doesn't get filled out on the form.

This is my code that I am using.

```
Sub AddDataToTomForm(AccessionNumber As String)

    Dim IE As Object 'Internet explorer object
    Dim objCollection As Object 'Variable used for cycling through different elements

    'Create IE Object
    IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    IE.Visible = True
    IE.Navigate("http://SampleWebSite.com") 'Your website

    Do While IE.Busy
        Application.DoEvents() 'This allows the site to load first
    Loop

    IE.document.GetElementById("ClientAccountNumber").SetAttribute("value", AccessionNumber) 'The "CustomerInfo.AccountNumber" is the name of the element I looked for in this case.

    ' Clean up
    IE = Nothing

End Sub
```

The form field should be filled out so that would mean the HTML would need to look like this:

```
<td>

<span class="QLSLabelReq" id="zenlbl_17">Client Accession</span>
    <div id="ClientAccession">
        <input class="text" id="ClientAccession" type="text"  value="TM123456P" size="30">

</div>

</td>
```

Comment: VBA is not the same as VB.Net. Which are you using? Please update the tags as necessary.

Comment: I have amended tags as this looks like vba to me. If it is indeed vba please confirm and then the question text needs editing, [edit], out of vb.Net

Comment: You should try contacting someone who can get the form corrected and tell them what the problem is. It could be causing other people problems. Of course, then you'd have to go back and adjust your code if they did fix it.

Comment: @QHarr IDK, `IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")` and `IE = Nothing` would both be missing a `Set` keyword in VBA. It does look quite VBA-y though. Definitely not an idiomatic .NET solution,

Comment: @MathieuGuindon    oh..... that is a very good point!

Comment: I have updated the tags. I am using VB.Net and not VBA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a type/tag in with id to get the right one. This matches then on both the tag and the id attribute. querySelector appears to apply to both .Net and vba.

```
ie.document.querySelector("input#ClientAccession").SetAttribute("value", someValue)
```

Comment: But how would I set the value of the second "ClientAccession" field using this? Could you type out the complete code for me please?

Comment: ie.document.querySelector("input#ClientAccession").SetAttribute("value", someValue)

Comment: Wow, it works! Is there an article that you know of that I can read about this?

Comment: Here you go: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors  and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelector